# getting menu event in activeX object from inserted menu item

Tags: activex, c++builder

I am inserting menu items from my activeX control into the container using ::InsertMenu(...).  The insertion works and my menu item shows up but I do not receive events for it (even though I have an event handler for the OnCLick()).  Of course this is because the event is going to the container and not to my control.  Is there any way in C++Builder to capture that event?  The container ignores it since it does not know how to handle the menu event itself, does it pass it onto the container, if so, how can I grab it?

Comment: What kind of ActiveX control are you creating? How are you obtaining the container's `HMENU` handle? Menu clicks are delivered to the menu's owner window, so if that belongs to the container then you have to require the container to reflect the click event back to you. If that is not an option, ie the container does not expose an interface to handle that reflection, such as via `IOleCommandTarget` or `IContextMenu`, then you might have to resort to a lower level message hook via `SetWindowsHookEx()` or `SetWinEventHook()` instead. Hard to say without more info about your setup, menu code, etc.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, I get the HWND of the main window passed to me.  Thats it.  Its a ActiveX Form, not a basic control.

Comment: I asked how you are getting the `HMENU` of the menu (which you need for `InsertMenu()`), not an `HWND` of a window. So now I assume you are using `GetMenu()` on the `HWND` you are given, is that right? That will only work if the ActiveXForm itself is the container of your control, not a child container, like a Panel. But either way, you will have to [subclass the `HWND`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/11/11/55653.aspx) of the menu owner (if you have it) to intercept `WM_COMMAND` messages for your menu items. Otherwise use a message hook.

Comment: That is correct, I am using GetMenu on the HWND passed in.  I can insert menu items and even replace the entire menu with a TMainMenu, but it seems that it is impossible to 'easily' get the events into the control. I will look into SetWindowSubclass().